# 8 to 3 Priority Encoder. Answer Verification

Tags: digital-logic, encoder, programmable-logic

[image]I am trying to design a priority encoder with a given priority table.

Input: I0 I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6 I7 
Priority: 2  7  6  1  5  0  3  4

Image attached!! Are these correct? Or I am failing?

[image: Priority Encoder Design]

Answer (score 0):

H equations are right but Y equations are not. Y's must be derived from H's not I's.

Y0 = H1 + H3 + H5 + H7

Y1 = H2 + H3 + H6 + H7

Y2 = H4 + H5 + H6 + H7

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues.

First, your output variable equations have to be written in terms of the intermediate H variables, rather than the inputs I.  Otherwise you just bypass the priority logic.

Second, it sounds like you have specifically assigned priorities, rather than "lowest channel = highest priority".  That is odd to me, but your truth table is a generic 8:3 priority encoder, not following the priority list you provided.

Comment: Ok! I uploaded another photo with the new work. All I need is to change the I's for the H's.